# Duplicated entries when listing out all values in an enumeration

Tags: c#, enums

I am writing a multi-keyboard framework. When I attempt to store the state (value) of different keys in a dictionary using System.Windows.Forms.Keys (key), I find my framework throwing ArgumentExceptions at me, saying duplicated keys are being added to the dictionary.

So I print out the entire enumeration to have a look, using this code.

```
foreach (Keys key in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Keys))) {
    Console.WriteLine(key+", "+(int) key);
}
```

And there are indeed duplicated values, and lots of them. Here are some of the duplicates:

```
Return, 13 (x2)
KanaMode, 21 (x3)
PrintScreen, 44 (x2)
```

Most of them are x2. But the keys that are common to have left and right versions are not duplicating though. For example,

```
ShiftKey, 16 (x1)
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the `Return` and `Enter` enum values have the same integer values. That is perfectly fine. Values in an enum don't have to be unique. In this case it even makes perfectly sense.

There the actual outline:

```
    //
    // Summary:
    //     The ENTER key.
    Enter = 13,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     The RETURN key.
    Return = 13,
```

When running `Enum.GetValues`, you actually get an array of id's. These id's are looked back, hence you have `13` twice, which both match to the first value found, in this case `Enter`.

I would suggest to check if an item is already added to the dictionary, and if not, add it:

```
Dictionary<Keys, string> keys = new Dictionary<Keys, string>();
foreach (Keys key in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Keys)))
{
    if (!keys.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        keys.Add(key, key.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: @Felastine: I updated the answer to give a little more explanation and solution for your dictionary problem.